# Declaring and initializing structure variables

Tags: c#, structure

This will be a quick question. I don't quite understand why this is happening so I'll show you what's bothering me through simple examples..

**First example:**

```
private static Point pt;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    pt.Display();
}

public struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X = {0}, Y = {1}", X, Y);
    }
}
```

**Second example:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Point pt;
    pt.Display();
}

public struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X = {0}, Y = {1}", X, Y);
    }
}
```

I may be missing something obvious, but first example compiles right and I get output on a console, and in the second example it won't even compile because:

*Local variable 'pt' might not be initialized before accessing.*

Well, it's not initialized in the first case either, but it does the job, what's the point?

**P.S. No pun intended.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class members that aren't initialized won't cause that compiler error because their scope is too broad for the compiler to determine if it could be initialized somewhere else.  It could be initialized in the the constructor, in any other class method, or even externally if it's `public`.  With a variable declared in local scope, the compiler can easily determine if the variable is initialized before it's used or not.

The "default" value for a struct is a struct with each of its fields set to the default value for it's type, so you effectively get a point with `X` and `Y` values of `(0,0)`.

If you had declared `Point` as a  `class` instead of a `struct` you'd have gotten a `NullReferenceException` at runtime because the reference would have a null value when you call `pt.Display()`.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case it's a `static` field and it will be automatically initialized by the compiler. In second case it's a local variable and you are responsible of initializing it, not the compiler.

Comment: Oh, so static keyword indicates to a compiler to initialize variables to default values?

Comment: @Smola no it has nothing to do with static. it's true for all class fields.for ex. if you have a reference type field and don't initialize it, you won't get an uninitialized error but you will get a NullReferenceException at runtime if you try to access it's members, because null is the default value for reference types.

Comment: So, if I got it right new class that contains Main method has been created automatically when I ran my program? Just like I wrote MyClass class = new MyClass(); and it automatically initialized my Point struct and it's variables to default values, but in the second example it's not the case because Point is not a private member of my startup class, but the local variable inside my main method?

Comment: yes exactly... I'm not sure about when your field is initialized to it's default value. it might be when the instance of MyClass is created or just before you try to access the static member. you can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) for more details

Comment: `static`, when used as a class field modifier, means that there will be only one instance of that object, and that it will be shared for all instances of the class.

Comment: @Selman22 Thank you for an answer, everything is clear to me now, I didn't think of my main class as if new instance of it was created on program startup so I got a bit confused. Thanks once agian :)

Comment: @Smola I think I was wrong about that. there is no need for an instance for program to start. the Main method is static and system calls that method to run your program, it shouldn't create an instance. probably the field initialization occurs before the main method call.